# iOS - How to post to twitter similar to facebook

Tags: ios, twitter

I'm MGTwitterEngine in my application to post status to twitter.

In my settings I am having switch that decides whether to post or not. When the switch is turned on and if twitter engine is not authorized, i'm asking for twitter login. And able to post to twitter.

But when I quit the app and start again, its not authorized any more.
But if you see facebook library for iOS, it retains the session between different app start ups. How can I make my app remember the twitter authentication when ever I restart my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter adopts the OAuth 1.0 protocol, you should be using this to authenticate. When you authenticate Twitter will give you an access token, you then use this access token for any authenticated requests such as posting a tweet. According to [Twitter's documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq), these access tokens never expire unless the user rejects your app or an admin suspends your app.

MGTwitterEngine has a MGTwitterEngineDelegate protocol that you should be adhering to, in this protocol there is a method defined as `- (void)accessTokenReceived:(OAToken *)aToken forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier` This method should be invoked when the access token is received, when it is invoked the received token is passed to it. Without any further knowledge of MGTwitterEngine you should capture this token and store it in a secure place such as the [Keychain Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html). Later when you build requests to twitter that must be authenticated, you can retrieve the access token from your Keychain and re-use it.

As I said, this is the process I would suggest without knowing much about MGTwitterEngine, I would expect that MGTwitterEngine handles the storage of the access token for you and re-uses it when necessary. But it might not be built that way.

Comment: Unless there was a new fork / release of MGTwitterEngine, do not use it as it fails on iOS5 from my experience. I would be happy to hear different answers on this issue as I kind of grew accustomed to it.

Comment: Good to know @Till, I would probably go with ShareKit, it seems to be pretty popular http://getsharekit.com/

Comment: ShareKit also is discontinued by the original authors and also has issues with iOS5. But then again, iOS5 brings native support so why not offering a native solution on >iOS5 platforms and using one of the alternatives on the others.

Comment: I was not aware SkareKit was discontinued, I would completely agree with using the built in Twitter integration for most purposes. It sounds like the OP has some lower level integration though, posting to twitter sounds like an optional addition to whatever the user is already doing. Similar to what Path 2.0 does, you can post to your Path but also include a Twitter post, Facebook post, and FourSquare checkin. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Using iOS twitter framework, we can use the app only on devices which has iOS5 running. But if I've to make the app run on iOS4 as well, I've to use MGTwitterEngine+OAuth. Now What is the alternative to make my app run on older devices as well?

Comment: Also for some user credentials its generating token properly and for some users its not creating token appropriately..... i couldn't debug because its a library which stopped me.

Comment: You are correct, if you want to target iOS4 then you will have to create your own or use something like MGTwitterEngine. If some user accounts are not consistently authenticating I would double check the accounts on Twitter.com. If they are fine there I would check the user/pass for any special characters that might not be getting escaped properly.